# Convert integers to char in Python

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn

I have the following code which implement's scikit-learn's Decision Tree Classifier:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree

# #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
with open('data/training.csv', 'r') as f:

    df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None)

Subset = df.iloc[:, 32:33]  # Just the labels
df['Num_Labels'] = df.Label.map(lambda x: '-1' if x == 's' else '1')  # Convert labels to '0' or '1'.

Z = df.iloc[:, 32:34]  # the letter labels & numerical labels
Train_values = df.iloc[:, 1:31].values
Train_labels = df.iloc[:, 33:34].values

with open('data/test.csv', 'r') as f2:

    df2 = pd.read_csv(f2, index_col=None)

Test_values = df2.iloc[:, 1:31].values

# #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

X = Train_values
Y = Train_labels.astype(np.float)

print X.dtype
print Y.dtype

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)

Pred = clf.predict(Test_values)

print Pred.dtype

Out = Pred.astype(np.float)
np.savetxt('Output_Numerical.csv', Out, delimiter=' ')
```

Up until this point the code works as expected. However after that I would like to convert the labels back into their original character values, 's' and 'h'. I wrote the following:

```
Out2 = Pred.astype(str)  # Initialize

print "Out2's type is:"
print Out2.dtype

for i in range(0, len(Out)):
    if Out[i] == -1:
        Out2[i] == 's'
    else:
        Out2[i] == 'h'

print Out2
```

but it doesn't change the values of Out2.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Sci-kit learn, but did you try Python's chr() function?

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: Most likely `Out2` will be a `ndarray` of suitable type (string of length 12 or something), so the operations are fine even though they look strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather simple, even though the error is not where you think:

```
for i in range(0, len(Out)):
    if Out[i] == -1:
        Out2[i] == 's'
    else:
        Out2[i] == 'h'
```

Use single `=` instead of `==` in the last two occasions! What happens now is that statement `Out2[1] == 's'` equals to `False`, which no one is interested in using. So it is not an illegal construct, and the interpreter has no reason to complain about it.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something simple like that